# When an iOS app is terminated/closed. Sending coordinates to server without user interaction.

Tags: ios, iphone, background-foreground

This will be submitted to Apple's App Store. When app is terminated (not in foreground or background), can we send user location coordinates to the server without user interaction?

Comment: If the app is "not in foreground or background", then the app is not running what-so-ever, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you could while the app is in the background, but your app would only get through the Apple review if the user was also being notified of the location for navigation purposes.

When the app is 'terminated' then it can't do anything.

Comment: +1 for "but your app would only get through the Apple review if the user was also being notified of the location for navigation purposes." Developers need to be very careful with using the user's location, especially when done "without user interaction" as Justin Wanajrat wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have control over your application while its in foreground/background state. But in case your app terminates then there is not way to do anything, as you donot have any control over it.

You can learn more about it from the [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).